# How to throw grenade or Molotov in GTA: Chinatown Wars on PSP?

Tags: psp, grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars

Well, I know that's on mobile we need just swipe, but have no idea how to throw on PSP. Pressing SELECT I only can choose from main weapons, so I only can see icon of secondary weapon in the right up corner. If you know, write combination of buttons, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Machienzo](https://www.neoseeker.com/forums/39986/t1483838-how-you-throw-molotov-cocktails/) (an user on Neoseeker, emph mine):

> It honestly is a simple as it sounds. **Just hold L, then push the Analog stick and hold it in the direction you want and push O**. If you're in a car, you can only throw it left and right of the vehicle through of the windows. If that by all means isn't working, make sure that you're buttons are still working.
>
> Can you see a Yellow or Green line coming from the player? If so, that means that L and the Analog Stick works. Maybe O is your problem. You can still use the Analog stick on your PSP no problem? Can still fire a Gun? Maybe the problem lies with L. Make sure your L button hasn't screwed up. After all that, it should work. You otherwise must be doing something wrong. =/